# How to use jquery-migrate with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jquery-migrate

After `npm install jquery-migrate`, I could just `require('jquery-migrate');` in the main `scripts.js` file. This works fine:

```
console.log(jQuery.migrateVersion); // JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 3.0.0
```

Now, I would like to set it so jquery-migrate is not present on the production version.

webpack.config.js:

```
var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod';
var webpack = require('webpack');
var dist = '/dist/js';

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: __dirname + '/src/js/scripts.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + dist,
        filename: 'scripts.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery',
            'jquery-migrate': 'jquery-migrate'
        }
    },
    plugins: dev ? [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'jquery-migrate': 'jquery-migrate'
        })
    ] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

This is not working:

```
console.log(jQuery.migrateVersion); // Undefined
```

How is it possible to load jquery-migrate form the webpack.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we did at work was to put the `require` within a production check.

```
if (__DEV__) {
  require('jquery-migrate');
}
```

You can have this if check as well: `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')`.

That way, webpack sees it's dead code when bundling for production, and won't parse the `require`, and thusly include the module.

To make those checks work, you should use the provide plugin to define them.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(dev) // Or some other check
    },
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(true) // or something
})
```

Neither the `ProvidePlugin` or `alias` is needed for `jquery-migrate`, btw :)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a global `__DEV__` variable accessible throughout your application via `webpack.config.js`.  Just add the following to your `plugins` array:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __DEV__: dev
    }),
    // other plugins
]
```

[Webpack - DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

Install `jquery-migrate` with:

```
npm install jquery-migrate --save-dev
```

Then in the entry point of your application (perhaps `app.js`) just add:

```
if (__DEV__) {
    require("jquery-migrate");
}
```

Also, some jquery plugins, like the latest version (at the time of this writing) of `jqueryCaret`, reference `window.jQuery` rather than just `jQuery`, so you may need to add the `'window.jQuery': 'jquery'` line to your `webpack.ProvidePlugin` constructor:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        '$': 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
    // other plugins
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inlining it into your `index.html` file. You can use some sort of environment variable to set whether or not you want the script to appear using the `html-webpack-plugin`. This plugin supports dynamic templateing that you could use.

The [documentation](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) is well written and I recommend you take a look at it!